# How to Extract Key from RSA from Bean Shell in Jmeter?

Tags: encryption, jmeter, rsa, jmeter-3.2

Using the Bean Shell Sampler , i am getting the below output .

Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22645393777802082209236016126079577098177798186319949526107968140080521355989491395183718699098362343956765929857695570321706899880729916472416104430270250740480253857977181966940781684127442660695227074768079572578868626318417847980637776060475992571920989510521398705182729749083041741535402186573338324131843221984077122743708605738053771684198051112417578154906794672470296699198396449111244295581371964621026618783235491999249933540697794384748872610581169875921473286879248291143441340394220262028972544072499684501740362635029199951979062722448893745158595281491224847156191030962211805545205128264731038824937

public exponent: 65537

I just need to extarct the Modulus value from the above ones. How can i achieve it using Regex Extractor in Jmeter ? Help is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4), apart from many bug fixes and performance improvements you will have a brand new [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) which makes extraction of everything between `modulus:` and `public exponent` easy as pie:

[image: JMeter Boundary Extractor]